# Enviar mensaje entre proceso hijo y padre

Tags: c

Partiendo de este codigo

```
void enviar(char palabra){
         printf("Escribe una palabra para enviar de H a P: ");
         scanf(" %c",&palabra);

 }

void my_handler(int signum){
        if (signum == SIGUSR1){
            printf("Recibido SIGUSR1! \n");
        }
}

int main ()
    {
    pid_t id_padre; /* PID del proceso padre */
    pid_t id_hijo;  /* PID del proceso hijo */
    int   estado;   /* Estado de salida */


    printf ("Inicio proceso padre. PID=%d\n", getpid ());
    id_padre = getpid ();
    if ((id_hijo = fork ()) == 0)
        {       /* Proceso hijo */
        printf ("Inicio proceso hijo. PID=%d, PPID=%d\n",
        getpid (), id_padre);
        sleep (3);
        printf ("Salida proceso hijo. PID=%d\n", getpid ());
        exit (getpid () > id_padre);        /* 1, si PID > PPID */
        }
    else
        {
        signal (SIGINT, SIG_IGN);        /* Ignorar CTRL-C */
        while (waitpid (id_hijo, &estado, 0) != id_hijo);
        if (WIFSIGNALED (estado))
            printf ("El proceso hijo ha recibido la señal %d\n", WTERMSIG (estado));
        if (WIFEXITED (estado))
           {
           printf ("Estado de salida del proceso hijo: %d\n", WEXITSTATUS (estado));
           if (WEXITSTATUS (estado) == 1)
               printf ("PID hijo > PID padre.\n");
           else
               printf ("PID padre > PID hijo.\n");
           }
        printf ("Fin del proceso %d\n", getpid ());
        exit (0);
    }


}
```

Me gustaria saber como mandar las señales `SIGUSR1` Y `SIGUSR2` al padre

Comment: ¿Qué problema has tenido enviando un [`kill` (ver ejemplo)](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Kill-Example.html)? ¿Qué has probado?

Comment: Vale gracias, ya he entendido como lanzar el mensaje con el kill, muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que puedes intentar es, inicialmente, mapear las señales que te interesan usando `signal`.

```
static int SIGUSR1_recibida = 0;
static int SIGUSR2_recibida = 0;

void procfunc(int sig)
{
  switch( sig )
  {
    case SIGUSR1:
      SIGUSR1_recibida = 1;
      break;
    case SIGUSR2:
      SIGUSR2_recibida = 1;
      break;
  }
}

int main()
{
  signal(SIGUSR1,procfunc);
  signal(SIGUSR2,procfunc);
}
```

Como ves, si se lanza una de estas señales se activará el flag correspondiente.

Para lanzar la señal basta con usar el método `kill`:

```
if ((id_hijo = fork ()) == 0)
{       /* Proceso hijo */
  kill(id_padre,SIGUSR1);
  kill(id_padre,SIGUSR2);
}
```

Y para recibirlas basta con leer los flags correspondientes:

```
else
{
  // espera activa
  while (!SIGUSR1_recibida) ;

  printf("SIGUSR1 recibida\n");

  while(!SIGUSR2_recibida) ;
  printf("SIGUSR2 recibida\n");
}
```

Poniéndolo todo junto:

```
static int SIGUSR1_recibida = 0;
static int SIGUSR2_recibida = 0;

void procfunc(int sig)
{
  switch( sig )
  {
    case SIGUSR1:
      SIGUSR1_recibida = 1;
      break;
    case SIGUSR2:
      SIGUSR2_recibida = 1;
      break;
  }
}

int main()
{
  signal(SIGUSR1,procfunc);
  signal(SIGUSR2,procfunc);

  pid_t id_padre = getpid ();
  pid_t id_hijo = fork();
  if(id_hijo < 0 )
  {
    printf("Error al crear el proceso hijo!!!!\n");
  }
  else if(id_hijo == 0)
  {       /* Proceso hijo */
    sleep(2);
    kill(id_padre,SIGUSR1);
    sleep(2);
    kill(id_padre,SIGUSR2);
  }
  else
  {
    // espera activa
    while (!SIGUSR1_recibida) ;

    printf("SIGUSR1 recibida\n");

    while(!SIGUSR2_recibida) ;
    printf("SIGUSR2 recibida\n");
  } 
}
```

El ejemplo se puede complementar con `time(NULL)` para implementar esperas con *timeout*.

Comment: Gracias con tu aporte y el compañero de arriba ya he entendido como lanzar los mensajes